# correct way of hiding HTML content

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I am writing a small HTML+JavaScript (so to call) application. User is given two choices (radio buttons) and depending what did he choose, I display content "A" or content "B" under the choice radio buttons.

Now I am wondering what is a right way to handle this content. Should I have 2 DIVs, only one visible, depending on choice, or should I use JavaScript to write InnerHTML to single div, depending on a state of radio buttons. This is small "calculation" application, so no forms data will be submitted.

Thanks for replies!
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
.myDivHidden
{
   display: none;
}

.myDiv
{
   display: block;
}

<div id="myDiv">
   Content
</div>
```

or

```
.myDivInvisible
{
   visibility: hidden;
}
.myDivVisible
{
   visibility: visible;
}

<div id="myDiv">
   Content
</div>
```

The difference is that `display: none;` will cause the element to disappear from the visible screen as if it is not even there, whereas `visibility: hidden;` will cause the element to disappear from view but still take up the space and other elements will not shift into the empty space like they would is you use `display: none;`.

Then you can swap the styles using JavaScript:

```
if (radio button check goes here)
{
   document.getElementById('myDiv').className = className; // display or visibility
}
else
{
   document.getElementById('myDiv').className = className; // display or visibility
}
```

Just swap the visibility classes according to the method you would prefer to use

Answer (score 0):

Use two divs, both belonging to a CSS class that includes the `display: none` rule. Then when the user selects a choice, override that CSS on the div you want displayed and undo the override on what you do not want to show. For example, if the user selects choice 1:

```
div1.style.display = 'block';
div2.style.display = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have 2 div and display the one which needs to be displayed. Dynamically writing the content makes it too hard to design it and brings no real value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 2 divs.   Embeding HTML into Javascript is ugly and makes it difficult to layout you page.

Answer (score 0):

Use both divs and then use `display: none;` for the div to hide.